# how to run a plugin with jetty in maven

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I have a jetty server and I want to run a class along with the server using maven.

The following structure is the relevant part of my project:

```
${basedir}/
  - pom.xml
  - server/
    - pom.xml
    - src/main/java/server/
      - NotificationTest.java
    - test/..
```

pom.xml in the server directory:

```xml
<!-- ... -->
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <httpConnector>
                        <port>8080</port>
                    </httpConnector>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>/test</contextPath>
                    </webApp>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.http2</groupId>
                        <artifactId>http2-server</artifactId>
                        <version>${jetty-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jetty-alpn-server</artifactId>
                        <version>${jetty-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<!-- ... -->
```

Currently, I have the following profile in the same pom.xml, in order to run the NotificationTest class:

```xml
<profiles>

    <profile>
        <id>databaseListener</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>java</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>server.NotificationTest</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

but in this way I need to run the two processes separately:

```
mvn jetty:run
exec:java -P databaseListener
```

How can I run them both in one command?

Comment: I think the issue you have is that jetty:run blocks additional maven execution until its complete? There is also jetty:run-forked http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#jetty-run-forked-goal that will spawn a new process. So "mvn jetty:run-forked exec:java -P databaseListener" might work already?

Comment: Perhaps you can use something like foreman (https://github.com/ddollar/foreman), but for the JVM? Like Gaffer: https://github.com/jingweno/gaffer, but yes it would be outside of maven

Comment: @wemu I tried your sollution but I can't see the output of the new process. So I can't tell if it really works!

in the output of jetty there is this line:
`[INFO] Forked process starting`

how can I see the output of the other process?

Comment: if you can connect to jetty it works :-) - the plugin has a section on system properties: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#setting-system-properties - there is an example on setting the logback configuration file. So that way you may be able to configure where the logs go and verify whats going on?